# About Ajax Upload image by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I want to use FormData Object to package a image and send it through Ajax.
But what I get is:

> java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
>   request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

This my code:

```js
function getId(arg) {
  return document.getElementById(arg);
}

function doFirst(){
  showPanel = getId("showPanel");
  sendbtn =  getId("sendbtn");
  mfile = getId("mFile");
  mfile.addEventListener('change',showUp,false);
}

function showUp(){
  var fReader = new FileReader();
  fReader.readAsDataURL(mfile.files[0]);
  fReader.onload = function (e){
  mImg = document.createElement("img");
  mImg.src=e.target.result;
  mImg.id ="mImg";
  showPanel.removeChild(showPanel.firstChild);
  showPanel.appendChild(mImg);     
  showPanel.replaceChild(showPanel.firstChild,showPanel.lastChild);
  
//first time what i wrote is using apprnd(); 
//var fd = new FormData();
//fd.append("myFile",mfile.files[0]);
    
//second time i through input all form to create a FormData object
  fd = new FormData(getIds("picForm"));
  
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
/*this section just for test
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
console.log("readyState"+xhr.readyState); 
console.log("status"+xhr.status);
}*/

  xhr.open("post","AddMemberPic");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
  xhr.send(fd);
  }
}
window.onload = doFirst;
```

```html
    <div id="showPanel">upload picture</div>
    <form action = "AddMemberPic" method = "post" id="picForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="mFile" id="mFile">
    </form>
```

What is wrong in my code? And why?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you comment out the xhr.setRequestHeader line does it magically start to work?

Comment: i had tried it. but ajax do not work..

Comment: "but ajax do not work" — That's not a helpful description of the problem. when you fix the problem  epascarello pointed out: What error messages do you get? What data is visible in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools?

Comment: if comment out xhr.setRequestHeader line. the readyState is 1 .and there no error message on browser...

Comment: Your code is missing the section which looks at the readyState

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files you have to store the file when your input is `change`d.
Heres a small snippet from [this tutorial](https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax):

```
// Variable to store your files
var files;

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event)
{
  files = event.target.files;
}
```

It uses jQuery but can be easily transferred to vanilla JavaScript.